# 3SUM problem (finding triplets) in better than O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm

Consider the following problem:

> Given an unsorted array of integers, find all triplets that satisfy x^2 + y^2 = z^2.
>
> For example if given array is `1, 3, 7, 5, 4, 12, 13`, the answer should be `5, 12, 13` and `3, 4, 5`

I suggest the below algorithm with complexity O(n^2):

- Sort the array in descending order, O(nlogn)
- square each element, O(n)

Now it reduces to the problem of finding all triplets(a,b,c) in a sorted array such that a = b+c.

The interviewer was insisting on a solution better than O(n^2).

I have read [3SUM problem on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM), which emphasizes problem can be solved in O(n+ulogu) if numbers are in range [-u,u] assuming the array can be represented as a bit vector. But I am not able to get a clear picture of further explanations.

Can someone please help me in understanding what is going on with a nice example?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Comment: another interview question that the interviewer studied for 3 hours and ask for an optimal solution from the interviewee in 5 minutes

Comment: @動靜能量 QFT. This kind of question is actually useless in determining a candidate potential. O(n^2) should be good enough for this trivia. When you need the O(n+u.log(u)) performance, you'll have much longer time to design it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all. Finding **all** triplets in worst case is `O(n^3)`. Suppose you have `n=3k` numbers. K of them are 3, k are 4 and k are 5.

```
3,....,3,4,....,4,5,.....5
```

There are `k^3 = n^3/27 = O(n^3)` such triplets. Just printing them takes `O(n^3)` time.

**Next will be explaining of 3SUM problem in such form:**

There are numbers `s_1, ..., s_n` each of them in range `[-u;u]`. How many triplets `a,b,c` there are that `a+b=c`?

1. transforming. Get 2*u numbers `a_-u, ..., a_0, a_1, ... a_u`. `a_i` is amount of numbers `s_j`, that `s_j = i`. This is done in `O(n+u)`
2. `res = a_0 * sum(i=-u..u, i=/=0, C(a_i, 2)) + C(a_0,3)` `a_0 = 0`
3. Build a polynom `P(x) = sum(i = -u...u, a_i*x^(i+u)`.
4. Find `Q(x) = P(x)*P(x)` using [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFT).
5. Note that `Q(x) = sum(i=-2u..2u, b_i*x^(i+2*u))`, where `b_i` is number of pairs `s_u`,`s_k` that `s_u+s_k = i` (This includes using same number twice).
6. For all even `i` do `b_i = b_i - a_(i/2)`. This will remove using same number twice.
7. Sum all `b_i*a_i/2` - add this to res.

**Example:** to be more simple, I will assume that range for numbers is [0..u] and won't use any +u in powers of x.
Suppose that we have numbers `1,2,3`
 - `a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 1`

- `res = 0`
- `P(x) = x + x^2 + x^3`
- `Q(x) =     x^2 +2x^3+3x^4+2x^5+x^6`
- After subtracting `b_2 = 0, b_3 = 2, b_4 = 2, b_5 = 2, b_6 = 0`
- `res += 0*1/2 + 2*1/2 + 2*0/2 + 2*0/2 + 6*0/2 = 1`

Comment: you should use the Omega notation instead of the Big-O in giving a lower bound on a complexity of the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility (who can fathom the mind of an interviewer?) would be to rewrite the equation as:

```
 x^2 + y^2 = z^2
 x^2 = z^2 - y^2 = (z-y)(z+y)
```

If we knew the prime factorisation of x^2 then we could simply iterate through all possible factorisations into a pair of numbers p,q (with p < q) and compute

```
 x^2 = p.q = (z-y)(z+y)
 p+q = (z-y)+(z+y) = 2z
 q-p = (z+y)-(z-y) = 2y
 z = (p+q)/2
 y = (q-p)/2
```

So given a factorisation x^2=p.q we can work out the z and y values. By putting all the integer values into a set we can then check each possible answer in time O(1) (per check) by looking to see if those z,y values are in the array (taking care that negative values are also detected).

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) that a randomly chosen integer has about log(n) divisors so this should take about n.log(n) assuming you can do the factorisation fast enough (e.g. if you knew all the integers were under a million you could precompute an array of the smallest factor for each integer).